# Leer archivo access desde php

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access-2010

Es posible leer directamente un archivo access desde php, sin usar odbc ni dns? Puedo hacerlo con archivos excel sin problemas, pero usando solo el archivo de access se puede? Ello para importar datos a una base mysql en la web. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Existe una clase para hacerlo que utiliza un objeto ADODB COM de Windows para abrir la base de datos mdb. A partir de eso, puede ejecutar consultas SQL y recuperar el conjunto de los resultados como con cualquier base de datos basada en SQL. esta es la clase: y [aquí](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/1700-PHP-Access-Microsoft-Access-mdb-database-files.html) puedes encontrar mayor explicación.

```
<?php    
class mdb 
{ 
  var $RS = 0; 
  var $ADODB = 0; 

  var $RecordsAffected; 

  var $strProvider = 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'; 
  var $strMode     = 'Mode=ReadWrite'; 
  var $strPSI      = 'Persist Security Info=False'; 
  var $strDataSource  = ''; 
  var $strConn     = ''; 
  var $strRealPath = ''; 

  var $recordcount = 0; 
  var $ok = false; 


  /** 
  * Constructor needs path to .mdb file 
  * 
  * @param string $dsn = path to *.mdb file 
  * @return boolean success  
  */ 
  function mdb( $dsn='Please enter DataSource!' ) 
  { 
    $this->strRealPath = realpath( $dsn ); 
    if( strlen( $this->strRealPath ) > 0 ) 
    { 
      $this->strDataSource = 'Data Source='.$this->strRealPath; 
      $result = true; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
      echo "<br>mdb::mdb() File not found $dsn<br>"; 
      $result = false; 
    } 

    $this->RecordsAffected = new VARIANT(); 

    $this->open(); 

  } // eof constructor mdb() 


  function open( ) 
  { 
    if( strlen( $this->strRealPath ) > 0 ) 
    { 

      $this->strConn =  
        $this->strProvider.';'. 
        $this->strDataSource.';'. 
        $this->strMode.';'. 
        $this->strPSI; 

      $this->ADODB = new COM( 'ADODB.Connection' ); 

      if( $this->ADODB ) 
      { 
        $this->ADODB->open( $this->strConn ); 

        $result = true; 
      } 
      else 
      { 
        echo '<br>mdb::open() ERROR with ADODB.Connection<br>'.$this->strConn; 
        $result = false; 
      } 
    } 

    $this->ok = $result; 

    return $result; 
  } // eof open() 


  /** 
  * Execute SQL-Statement 
  * @param string $strSQL = sql statement 
  * @param boolean $getrecordcount = true when a record count is wanted 
  */ 
  function execute( $strSQL, $getrecordcount = false ) 
  { 

    $this->RS = $this->ADODB->execute( $strSQL, &$this->RecordsAffected ); 

    if( $getrecordcount == true ) 
    { 

      $this->RS->MoveFirst(); 
      $this->recordcount = 0; 

      # brute force loop 
      while( $this->RS->EOF == false ) 
      { 
        $this->recordcount++; 
        $this->RS->MoveNext(); 
      } 
      $this->RS->MoveFirst(); 

    } 


  } // eof execute() 

  function eof() 
  { 
    return $this->RS->EOF; 
  } // eof eof() 

  function movenext( ) 
  { 
    $this->RS->MoveNext(); 
  } // eof movenext() 

  function movefirst() 
  { 
    $this->RS->MoveFirst(); 
  } // eof movefirst() 

  function close() 
  { 

    @$this->RS->Close(); // Generates a warning when without "@" 
    $this->RS=null; 

    @$this->ADODB->Close(); 
    $this->ADODB=null; 
  } // eof close() 

  function fieldvalue( $fieldname ) 
  { 
    return $this->RS->Fields[$fieldname]->value; 
  } // eof fieldvalue() 

  function fieldname( $fieldnumber ) 
  { 
    return $this->RS->Fields[$fieldnumber]->name; 
  } // eof fieldname() 

  function fieldcount( ) 
  { 
    return $this->RS->Fields->Count; 
  } // eof fieldcount()   

} // eoc mdb 
?>
```